# Sorting a generic list descendingly, removing values and sorting it ascendingly by different properties results in unexpected list

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a list with a special type:

```
List<Spitzen_Frequenz_und_Wert> spitzenliste = new List<Spitzen_Frequenz_und_Wert>();

//... 

public class Spitzen_Frequenz_und_Wert
{
    public double Frequenz;
    public double Wert;
}
```

I am adding values to *spitzenliste*. It looks like this(example):

```
Frequenz;Wert
1;0.1
2;0.8
3;0.2
4;0.9
5;0.2
6;0.8
```

I want to filter this list descendingly by *Wert*, so in our example

```
Frequenz;Wert
4;0.9
2;0.8
6;0.8
5;0.2
3;0.2
1;0.1
```

Then I want to keep only the first 5 entries

```
Frequenz;Wert
4;0.9
2;0.8
6;0.8
5;0.2
3;0.2
```

Then I want to sort ascendingly by *Frequenz*

```
Frequenz;Wert
2;0.8
3;0.2
4;0.9
5;0.2
6;0.8
```

My approach

```
var NachGrößeSortiert = spitzenliste.OrderByDescending(Spitzen_Frequenz_und_Wert => Spitzen_Frequenz_und_Wert.Wert).ToList();
NachGrößeSortiert.RemoveRange(5, NachGrößeSortiert.Count - 5);
var NachFrequenzSortiert = NachGrößeSortiert.OrderBy(Spitzen_Frequenz_und_Wert => Spitzen_Frequenz_und_Wert.Frequenz);
foreach (var kklm in NachFrequenzSortiert)
{
    db(kklm.Frequenz + ";" + kklm.Wert);
}
```

results something like

```
Frequenz;Wert
1;0.1
1;0.8
1;0.2
...
```

What is wrong?

EDIT: The formulas work but spitzenliste had the wrong values. I corrected it and it worked.

Comment: ListenToYourBody, you can NOT delete a question with answers for a reason so vandalizing your own question is obviously not allowed.

Comment: As you blocked me I do as I please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descending - is sorting from a greater value to a smaller one. While your example shows, that you need the list to be sorted from the smaller to the greater.

Also, as soon as you have no need to modify the original list, you may use `Take` for the same task:

```
var result = spitzenliste.OrderBy(s=>s.Wert)
                         .Take(5)
                         .OrderBy(s=>s.Frequenz)
```

The example above will produce output (`Wert` = 0.9 is omitted here):

```
1:  0,1
2:  0,8
3:  0,2
5:  0,2
6:  0,8
```

while if you use `OrderByDescending(s=>s.Wert)`, you'll get

```
2:  0,8
3:  0,2
4:  0,9
5:  0,2
6:  0,8
```

`Wert` = 0.1 is omitted here

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the words ascending and descending. Try reversing that.

It looks like you sort it ascendingly in both orderings. Ascending is "smallest first, values increase through sequence".